# DataTrigger: complex condition for "Value" property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I have a ListBox in which I store LogEvents. The LogEvent class contains a String property named "Event". I need to apply a specific style based on the content of that property. However, the condition is not based on a static value, but on a condition like Event.Contains("blabla").

I think the simplest way to do this is to use DataTriggers on the style to apply and a ValueConverter in which I would apply the condition and convert the result to a static value for the "Value" property of the DataTrigger. Is there a more elegant way to do this without using a Converter, which I don't particularly like?

Comment: I don't think you can use a binding or converter on the `Value` property of a `DataTrigger`. If you have more than one bound value that determines the result, you're best off using an `IMultiValueConverter` and passing it the values you need. That said, a DataTrigger+Converter is probably the simplest solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps a more elegant solution would be to create a `DataTemplateSelector` and you wire it in to your listbox like so - `ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"`